# Looping through a DataFrame and Sending Email Using RDCOMClient

Tags: r, loops, email, rdcomclient

I have tried this code several different ways and keep getting the same error. I don't believe the code is the issue, I'm wondering if there is a functionality of RDCOMClient I am missing. The functionality works, as I have sent many emails through this. It is the looping functionality that is not working.

I am simply trying to loop through a vector of a DataFrame and send out an email corresponding to the email it is looping over.

(e.g., an email should be sent to email1, an email should be sent to email2, etc.)

```
test.df <- data.frame(
                      "email" = c("email1", "email2", "email3")
                      ,"name" = c("name1", "name2", "name3")
                      )
```

```
mail_fun <- function(mail) {
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  ## configure  email parameter
  outMail[["To"]] = mail
  outMail[["subject"]] = "Project hours for next week"
  outMail[["HTMLBody"]] = paste0("<p>Testing sending hours through R</>")
  ## send it
  outMail$Send()
}
```

```
sapply(test.df$email, mail_fun)
```

**This is the error I am receiving:**

> Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, "To", value = 2L) : 
>     Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>
> Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, "To", value = 2L) : 
>     Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same error. I believe you also need to have the `RDCOMServer` package installed, or am I wrong? I'm trying this out and will loop back to you!

Comment: I actually figured it out after more research. It's because the emails were factors instead of strings. I just added stringsAsFactors = FALSE to my data.frame().

Comment: Ah-ha. That makes sense-- I learned something new today, thanks.

Comment: maybe you can post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The data.frame named test.df contains factors, not strings. So you are assigning a value from a factor to outMail[["To"]]. That value is an integer, in this case 1L. So that is wrong. As the answer above says, make these strings. Use:

```
test.df <- data.frame(to = c(...), ..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```